# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).weather is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem with this code:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).weather is not a function

cant not showing weather information cause error type

```js
google.load('maps', '3', {
    other_params: "sensor=false"
});
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    $("#weather").weather({
        days: 10, 
        showall: true
    });
});
```

But I still have the same problem .

Comment: Is your `weather` plugin loaded?

Comment: yes weather plugin loaded

Comment: what do you get in console if you write: `jQuery.fn.weather`? Also, do you have any other plugin that may be causing issues with jQuery's `$` ?

Comment: you can see here on my page http://meteoiraq.at.ua/index/halt_altqs/0-5

Comment: Try changing `$` by `jQuery` in your selector.

Comment: how i dont understand

Comment: Check my answer. It says what you should change. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks , but still same problem

Comment: Something changed in your page because the first time i checked it, there existed `jQuery.fn.weather`  but now it doesn't exist. So, it seems that you are not loading your plugin correctly. `http://meteoiraq.at.ua/js/weather.js` isn't loading any jQuery plugin, so, you might be doing something wrong.

Comment: yes i edit now the http://meteoiraq.at.ua/js/weather.js but still same problem

Comment: It isn't a jQuery plugin yet.

Comment: check now i fixed http://meteoiraq.at.ua/js/weather.js but still Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).weather is not a function

Comment: Again. `http://meteoiraq.at.ua/js/weather.js` is not a jQuery plugin. I don't see any change. There should be something similar to `jQuery.fn.weather = ...`

Comment: in fact i dont know what i do , thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It seems that jQuery's `$` is being overwritten by some other plugin or extension you are using. Try using `jQuery` instead `$` to avoid those kind of problems.
In your case, try:

```
google.load('maps', '3', {
    other_params: "sensor=false"
});
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
    jQuery("#weather").weather({
        days: 10, 
        showall: true
    });
});
```